# react-scrollable-anchor stops working when wrapped in 100vh

Tags: css, reactjs, scrollspy

I am trying to fix this top heading while keeping the scrollspy working but to fix it either I have to use position fixed and then it takes the width of the whole page or I tried using position sticky with top 0 but it doesn't work and as soon as I wrap it in 100vh it starts working but scrollspy stops working. any idea how to solve this issue? it's really important to make it responsive so cannot use any px value for width as well.

update - I have tried my best to replicate the problem in the sandbox link [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-scrollspy-tgu5f). you can see the issue in different resolutions through inspect.

[image]

Comment: Okay. But how can we see the code? Can you make a demo out of it through Stackblitz or Codesandbox?

Comment: @m4n0 I've updated the code sandbox link. I hope you'll get some idea regarding my problem through that